# Change of 'role' of variables in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential

I would appreciate some help understanding a variable change in an equation a textbook I'm reading is working through.

The book is trying to illustrate the role of changing the roles of x and y in a differential equation so that we have a linear equation we can solve more easily. However, I think there are some steps missing.

**I am given:**

**(i)** $y\ ln(y) + [x-ln(y)]\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

And told by changing the roles of x and y I will get:

**(ii)** $\frac{dx}{dy} +\frac{x}{yln(y)} =\frac{1}{y} $

Which I can then start to solve using an integrating factor.Everything after the 'change of roles' I'm OK with. However, I can't seem to see how we got from **i** to **ii**?

What am I not seeing? i.e. what is the procedure?

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$ Using this relationship simply rearrange the first equation algebraically.

Comment: This was super helpful thank you. I had spend a bit of time with it, but got there. Appreciate the hint. Thank you, I will write up the procedure below. Feel free to correct.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Ninad for the hint. Don't know how to tag in an answer, but hope you see the thank you.

The process of changing the roles of the variable in the differential equation $y\ln(y)+[x-\ln(y)]\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ is as follows:

**Method**

1. Identify the reciprocal
2. Solve for the reciprocal
3. Rewrite the equation in a linear form
4. Solve the differential equation with an integrating factor

**Steps to rearrange as follows:**

(a) $y\ln(y)+[x-\ln(y)]\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

(b) $y\ln(y)+[x-\ln(y)]\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}=0$

(c) $[x-\ln(y)]\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}=y\ln(y)$

(d) $[x-\ln(y)]=y\ln(y)\frac{dx}{dy}$

(e) $[x-\ln(y)]=y\ln(y)\frac{dx}{dy}$

(f) $\therefore$ $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{[x-\ln(y)]}{y\ln(y)}$

(g) $\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{x}{y\ln(y)}=-\frac{ln(y)}{y\ln(y)}$

(h) $\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{x}{y\ln(y)}=-\frac{1}{y}$

From here it can be solved using the method of the integrating factor.